# Secondary y axis limit in pandas plot

Tags: pandas, plot

Is there a way to set the limit for the secondary Y axis in pandas df.plot

I have the following plotting statement. Is there a way to simply add ylim for secondary axis? as in "secondary_ylim=(0,1)"

```
df[["Date","Col1","Col2"]].plot(x="date",y=["Col1","Col2"],secondary_y="Col2",ylim = (0,1))
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Interesting.... I don't know if there is another way to get the axes for the secondary y_axes.

But, you could do it this way:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date':pd.date_range('2019-02-01', periods=10), 'Col1':np.random.randint(0,10,10), 'Col2':np.random.randint(100,500, 10)})
ax = df[["Date","Col1","Col2"]].plot(x="Date",y=["Col1","Col2"],secondary_y="Col2", ylim = ([0,5]))
ax.set_ylim(0,5)
fig = ax.get_figure()
ax = fig.get_axes()
ax[1].set_ylim(0,250)
```

or as @Stef points out, you can use the `right_ax`

```
ax = df[["Date","Col1","Col2"]].plot(x="Date",y=["Col1","Col2"],secondary_y="Col2", ylim = ([0,5]))
ax.right_ax.set_ylim(0,250)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest  Do you have a better way?

Comment: or simply `ax.right_ax.set_ylim(0,250)` (using the `ax` returned by `plot`)